# git tag with gpg-agent and pinentry-curses

Tags: git, gnupg

When using gpg-agent with git tag -u, I'm getting the following error immediately:

```
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: skipped "my@email.com": bad passphrase
gpg: signing failed: bad passphrase
error: gpg failed to sign the data
error: unable to sign the tag
```

gpg-agent.conf:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

When I unlock the key first (via a `gpg -e -s test.txt`), then the `git tag -u` command picks up the key and signs the tag as expected.

This is on ubuntu 13.10, using i3 wm. I'd be suspicious that gnome-keyring is somehow hampering...something, but on an raspberry pi, running archlinux-arm, it works the same way, but with a slightly different issue -- After running the `git tag -u` command, it asks for a password to unlock, but no pinentry or prompt appears. After a time (about 30 seconds), it fails with the following:

```
gpg: problem with the agent: Line passed to IPC too long
gpg: skipped "my@email.com": Operation cancelled
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled
error: gpg failed to sign the data
error: unable to sign the tag
```

Again, once I unlock the key with a straight `gpg -s` to an arbitrary file to cache the credentials in gpg-agent, the tag is signed without issue.

My assumption is that something is weird with my useage of pinentry-curses. I have already updated /usr/bin/pinentry to point to /usr/bin/pinentry-curses, but the problem persists.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get git to play nice with gpg/pinentry?

- ubuntu gpg version: 1.4.14
- archlinux-arm gpg version: gnupg-2.0.22-1

EDIT: running zsh. Here is the relevant bit sourced for the gpg agent:

```
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ] ; then
    envfile="$HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env"
    if [[ -e "$envfile" ]] && kill -0 $(grep GPG_AGENT_INFO "$envfile" | cut -d: -f 2) 2>/dev/null; then
        eval "$(cat "$envfile")"
    else
        eval "$(gpg-agent --daemon --write-env-file "$envfile")"
    fi
    export GPG_AGENT_INFO  # the env file does not contain the export statement
fi
```

when I follow $(tty) (eg: `/dev/pts/16`) the ownsership is already `user:tty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will also need to export the **GPG_TTY** variable every time when you start a new TTY (could also be done from bash/zsh rc files):

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems with the Pinentry ncurses dialog are related to the ownership of the TTY pinentry tries to use (if you initially login as a user & then su for example).

Put the following script into **/etc/profile.d/gpg-agent.sh** to fix it ( you may want to omit the outer `if` on a multi user system or change the condition to != )  :

```
if [ "$(id -un)" = "root" ] ; then
    envfile="$HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env"
    if [[ -e "$envfile" ]] && kill -0 $(grep GPG_AGENT_INFO "$envfile" | cut -d: -f 2) 2>/dev/null; then
        eval "$(cat "$envfile")"
    else
        eval "$(gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --write-env-file "$envfile")"
    fi

    export GPG_AGENT_INFO    # the env file does not contain the export statement
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK     # enable gpg-agent for ssh

    GPG_TTY=$(tty)
    chown $USER:tty $GPG_TTY # make pinentry-ncurses work
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers -- however, I've already got something like that in my .zshrc, all except for the chown, but it's still no good. The permissions in `/dev/pts` are already set correctly. Adding the chown did not resolve the issue. The only difference between your snippet and mine is that I'm not enabling my gpg agent for ssh. I couldn't see that as making a difference, would it?

Comment: I was having similar problem with Duply / Duplicity signing backups - the solution was from the [GnuPG in Automated Environments FAQ](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/GnuPG-FAQ.html#how-can-i-use-gnupg-in-an-automated-environment). On Alpine Linux I still need the chown for     pinentry-curses to work correctly (so you may do on Arch too) - Debian does not need     chown on the tty.